# Trouble updating React.js state from <textarea>

Tags: reactjs, textarea, onchange

I have form with preloaded information for editing existing objects. When i edit information in input field everything goes ok, but when i trying to edit content in textarea text becomes unavailable for typing. If i change attribute 'value' to 'defaultValue' old text not displayed in textarea. My component code:

```
class PostEdit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      post: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showPost(this.state.id);
  }

  showPost(id){
    fetch(`/api/v1/posts/${id}`, 
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    }).then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((data) => {this.setState({ post: data }) });
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render () {
    const { name, content } = this.state.post;
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input id="name" className="form-control" type="text" name="name" defaultValue={name} onChange={this.onChange} required />
          <textarea id="content"  className="form-control" name="content" rows="8" cols="40" defaultValue={content} onChange={this.onChange}></textarea>    
          <input type="submit" value="Save" className="btn btn-success" id="btn-submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What i doing wrong and how can I make the textarea work properly?

Comment: What is the intended type of `this.state.post` supposed to be? In your `render()` function, you are treating it as an object grabbing object properties such as `name` and `content`, in `showPost()` and on initialization you are treating it as an array. Did you intend for `content` and `name` to live as properties in `this.state.post`? Are you okay with `name` and `content` being outside of `this.state.post`?

Comment: Post looks like `{"id": 2,"name": "name","content": "content"}`. There is simplified example. in fact, there are a lot of fields (about 30) and it will be too much duplicate code if each property will be outside.

Comment: See my answer and working example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending for `name` and `content` to be properties in `this.state.post` then update the initial `this.state` in your `constructor` at minimum changing the type from an array `[]` to an object `{}` and update your `onChange()` handler to target `this.state.post`. Also you'd need to use the `value` attribute on the input and textarea instead of `defaultValue`:

```
class PostEdit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      post: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showPost(this.state.id); // may consider using this.props.match.params.id instead here
  }

  showPost(id){
    fetch(`/api/v1/posts/${id}`, 
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    }).then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((data) => {this.setState({ post: data }) });
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ post: { ...this.state.post, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } });
  }

  render () {
    const { name, content } = this.state.post;
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input id="name" className="form-control" type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.onChange} required />
          <textarea id="content"  className="form-control" name="content" rows="8" cols="40" value={content} onChange={this.onChange}></textarea>    
          <input type="submit" value="Save" className="btn btn-success" id="btn-submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hwgpbs) in action.

Hopefully that helps!